# HTML5 appcache manifest file extension

Tags: html, specifications, offlineapps

I read this line from  [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com)  :

```
HTML Manifest files now use .appcache extension instead of .manifest, 
as per http://html5.org/r/5812.
```

And I saw this from http://html5.org/r/5812

```
Change the suggested extension for appcache manifests from .manifest to .appcache 
to avoid clashing with Microsoft's unregistered application/manifest type
```

Here is my question. What is **Microsoft's unregistered application/manifest type** and when does it clash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Microsoft technology is proprietary and related to synchronising sites / applications between IIS instances I think.

The "clash" relates to the fact that off-line cache manifest files typically use the `.manifest` file extension, but require a MIME type of `text/cache-manifest` to work, whereas the unrelated MS `.manifest` files use the MIME type you mention, i.e. `application/manifest`